# Hadoop - Recursive copy/put from local to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I can use `hadoop fs -put local hdfs` to copy from local to HDFS. Is there a way to do recursive put? Tried `-put -r` and it doesnt work.

Comment: You can put a directory. There is no option like -r. Simply mention the directory.

Comment: @AmalGJose, that works!

Answer (score 7):

Try this command

> hadoop fs -copyFromLocal docs/* /input/

Where /input/ is the path of the HDFS location where you want to store.

> hadoop fs -copyFromLocal local/* /Hdfs/